# What can be the possible cause of this error in xcode PBXcp Main.storyboardc is longer than filepath buffer size (1025)?

Tags: ios, xctest

My app target is building and running successfully on a device but I am facing this error while running the unit test target for my app. It specifically occurs during the copying face.

> PBXCp
>   /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fxuhlekykqtnhocptuufcbrgmspb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app
>   /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fxuhlekykqtnhocptuufcbrgmspb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app
>       cd /Users/MyUser/Documents/MyApp-iOSApp
>       export PATH="/Users/MyUser/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/MyUser/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -exclude Headers -exclude PrivateHeaders -exclude Modules -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fxuhlekykqtnhocptuufcbrgmspb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app
>   /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fxuhlekykqtnhocptuufcbrgmspb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks
>
> error:
>   '/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fxuhlekykqtnhocptuufcbrgmspb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyAppTests.xctest/Frameworks/MyApp.app/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc/34u-hk-bLl-view-84B-ld-hA4.nib'
>   is longer than filepath buffer size (1025).

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the DerivedData folder?

Comment: Yeah I have tried that multiple times. Also tried to change the framework and header search paths but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Look like build dependency cycle. I had reproduce log like yours when added AppName.app into `Copy bundle resources` section  of test target.

Answer (score 4):

Roman's Answer is what did it for me.   I had a circular dependency where appname.app was in my copy resources.   I don't fully understand why removing that fixed the issue, but I figured I'd post here.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your storyboard size is too large try breaking your storyboard file into multiple storyboards using storyboard references

watch this tutorial for storyboard reference :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xxbflasmOc

Hope this be the right answer and helps you